# What 3d software is best to draw topological and complex objects?

Tags: general-topology, 3d, math-software, cross-product

I am working on making 3d objects like Cartesian product of $T×T$, $8×8$ and double torus. Also, I should also be able to cut those objects and plot points on it and split the objects into different shapes. I have been trying on Fusion 360, but can't figure out.

Comment: DId the prof/book not suggest any?

Comment: No. She just said to use Rhino, but I didn't like the software.